# Codeigniter 3 - Highcharts mysql json example

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, highcharts

I'm Trying to create a bar chart using Highcharts for my Codeigniter project

Created Controller, View & Model with relevant Routes

## tbl_demo_viewer table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_demo_viewer` (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `numberofview` int(11) NOT NULL,

  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

## tbl_demo_click table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_demo_click` (

  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

  `numberofclick` int(12) NOT NULL,

  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

## application/config/database.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');


$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;


$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'h_sole',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

## application/config/routes.php

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['my-chart'] = "Chart";
```

## application/controllers/Chart.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Chart extends FZ_Controller {   

   public function __construct() {
       parent::__construct();
       $this->load->model('Chart_model');
    } 

        public function createChart()
    {


        $this->data['click'] = $this->Chart_model->getClick();        
        $this->data['viewer'] = $this->Chart_model->getViewer();      

        $bc = array(array('link' => base_url(), 'page' => 'Home'), array('link' => '#', 'page' => 'Demo'));
        $meta = array('page_title' => 'Demo', 'bc' => $bc);
        $this->render('my_chart', $meta, $this->data);
    }
}
```

## application/models/Chart_model.php

```
<?php

class Chart_model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function getViewer() {

        $this->db->set_dbprefix('');

        $this->db->select('SUM(numberofview) as count');
        $this->db->from('tbl_demo_viewer');       
        $this->db->group_by('tbl_demo_viewer.created_at');
        $this->db->order_by('tbl_demo_viewer.created_at');
        $q = $this->db->get();
    }

    public function getClick() {

        $this->db->set_dbprefix('');

        $this->db->select('SUM(numberofclick) as count');
        $this->db->from('tbl_demo_click');       
        $this->db->group_by('tbl_demo_click.created_at');
        $this->db->order_by('tbl_demo_click.created_at');
        $q = $this->db->get();
    }  

}
```

## application/views/my_chart.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HighChart</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>


    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () { 

    var data_click = <?php echo $click; ?>;
    var data_viewer = <?php echo $viewer; ?>;

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Yearly Website Ratio'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['2013','2014','2015', '2016']
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Rate'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Click',
            data: data_click
        }, {
            name: 'View',
            data: data_viewer
        }]
    });
});

</script>

<div class="container">
    <br/>
    <h2 class="text-center">Codeigniter 3 - Highcharts mysql json example</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Chart Example</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div id="container"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

No error fired. But did not created the desired chart. I can not understand what I am going wrong. Can anyone help me ?

Comment: That is *a lot* to go through. I would suggest focusing less on the code per-say, and more on the what. What exactly is happening? Are you js variables getting populated? If so, have you checked the formatting - I'm not seeing any json encoding, what exactly are these functions outputting?

Comment: Could you show the result of js variables `data_click` and `data_viewer `?

Comment: @Wojciech Chmiel. Could n't

Comment: I' m not a PHP expert so I can only help you with js code that seems to be good. However, without seeing those variables, I can't help you.